# display only selected column from SQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using a form to store details in SQL. Here is the SQL table 
CODE

```
CREATE TABLE `mobile` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`place` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`type` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile1` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile2` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile3` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile4` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilebrand` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilemodel` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilecond` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`price` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`location` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`description` longtext NOT NULL,
`youare` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`phonenumber` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`view` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
`reply` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I'm using PHP to display display result form SQL

- Now what I want is to display only selected PLACE (its location of user submitted by user)
- TYPES are mobile, tablet, accessories

How do I apply 2 filters at same time?

Comment: With a `WHERE`clause and two conditions combined with the `AND` operator. Please use parameterized prepared statements with PDO or mysqli to get this done.

Comment: where is your select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a normal `AND` operator in your  `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
        place = '<your filter>'
    AND
        types IN ('mobile', 'tablet', 'accessories')
```

As @VMai likes to remind, remember to sanitize your filter before including it in the query. A fast Google search will enlighten you with the best practices for doing this.

Comment: Oh the quotes are just an oversight, I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: And about the parameters, it's just a little example concerning the use of SQL operators, I didn't lost time to sanitizing the input and formatting the query.

Comment: I know, but is it really so much more work to write at least three lines with prepare, bind, execute omitting the error handling to promote better practice?

Comment: There are thousands of better practice for doing this kind of things, but they are not in topic with the answer so I don't see your point.

Answer (score 0):

your sql will look something like this:

```
$type="mobile";
$sql =" select * from mobile where place='<filter value>' and type=$type";
```

if type is not know and you have already the fix list of type then use in operater.

```
 $sql =" select * from mobile where place='<filter value>' and type in ('mobile','tablet','accessories')";
```

then use `mysqli` or `pdo` to execute this.

Comment: $location should be better replaced by a placeholder else enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
select * from mobile where place="place1" and type="mobile"
```

Add more places & types using AND / OR as needed